# Approaches to Extend ng2-pdf-viewer to support drawing on top of pdf?

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, canvas, pdf.js

I am making use of **ng2-pdf-viewer** as a PDF Viewer Component in my application, now *I want to extend the component to support drawing on top of pdf, in summary adding a pencil or something that will help me to draw shapes etc on the pdf.*

What could be the possible approaches to achieve the same? Like a **layer of canvas** or something? or do we have some package in npm that has high level support for **text, drawing and images.**

Even I tried looking for npm packages, for supporting drawing on pdf, or pdf packages itself like **ngx-extended-pdf-viewer**, **simple-pdf-viewer** but unfortunately didn't found any solution.

For instance an example of what I mean by drawing is attached as follows by leveraging *acrobat reader drawing* capabilities.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After receiving no answers to the Question, I ended up solving the problem my-self, I have written my own layer of canvas over the **ng2-pdf-viewer**, and extended the functionality of the layer to change the stroke size, width, color using **color-picker**, and even retaining the canvas pixels on **ng2-pdf-viewer** after zooming in/out pdf in ng2-pdf-viewer.

Soon, I will create a fiddle for same, as script is long.

Comment: Whow! I like the idea. It sounds like an impressive challenge. Did you already publish your fiddle?

Comment: @StephanRauh ya but I did it in the company I was working for, so it was company project then but yes it is possible.

Comment: @StephanRauh the approach is somewhat like this, what you need to do is to have a transparent layer of canves over pdf-reader , and then you can have a color picker to take care of strokes of different colours by modifiying strokes of canvas on every new selection of color, and the biggest challenge when I implemented it was the storing of coordinates and resizing, scaling and transforming canvas so that we won't lose data of coordinates and other challenges were to retain data on zooming pdf, zooming browser etc.

Comment: I'd like to invite you to provide a demo to https://pdfviewer.net. Of course, you have to follow your company's rules on copyright. But if it's possible, it'd be great! Judging from the GitHub request, I feel it might be inspiring to many developers. Interested? Contact me at webmaster1 (at) beyondjava (dot) de.

Comment: Hi!
Can you please share your solution? I would love to see it!!!

Comment: @DivyanshuRawat Have a similar requirement - would be great to look at the code for your approach!